# How to change page in next js with react-router-dom

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-router-dom

I want to change the page if the login was successful but I get this error message:

[image]

with this code:

```
export default function SignUp() {
  const trigger = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    try {
      const response = await fetchRestEndpoint(`/users`, 'POST', {
        username: data.get("username"),
        email: data.get("email"),
        password: data.get("password"),
        role: "user"
      });
    if (response.ok) {
      const user: any = await response.json();
      console.log(user);
      navigate('/');
    }
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
  ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js provides its own router. You do not need to use `react-router-dom`. I strongly recommend you take a look at the [related documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing).

##### When using the pages directory

```
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const login = useCallback(() => {
    // ...
    router.push("/some-url")
  }, [router]);

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

##### When using the app directory

```
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const login = useCallback(() => {
    // ...
    router.push("/some-url")
  }, [router]);

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are breaking the rules of hooks by calling a React hook from a callback function. React hooks must only be called at the top level, e.g. in the body of a React function component, or a custom React hook.

Move the `useNavigate` hook out of the callback.

```
export default function SignUp() {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // <-- call in function body

  const trigger = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

    try {
      const response = await fetchRestEndpoint("/users", "POST", {
        username: data.get("username"),
        email: data.get("email"),
        password: data.get("password"),
        role: "user"
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const user: any = await response.json();
        console.log(user);
        navigate('/');
      }
    } catch(e) {
      alert(e);
    }

  ...
```